# Cancel Long operation from Angular to .NET Core

Tags: c#, angular, asp.net-core, abp

I try to send a cancellation request (on c# AspNetCore based on Abp Boilerplate) from Angular client (use Observable -> unsubscribe...) to cancel long Task Operation but API not fire.

```cs
    [HttpPost]
        public async Task<GetDataOutputDto> GetDataLongOperation(CustomInputDto input)
        {
            try
            {
                var tokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource(); // _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.RequestAborted;
                tokenSource.CancelAfter(2500);

                var token = _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.RequestAborted; //tokenSource.Token;

                var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings
                {
                    Error = (sender, args) => {
                        args.ErrorContext.Handled = true;
                    },
                    MissingMemberHandling = MissingMemberHandling.Ignore
                };


                //... remove for brev
        }
```

on angular side

```js
                this.subscription = this.loadData(undefined).subscribe(res=>{
                    console.log('data loaded!');
                    this.localData = res.data;
                    //this._rawData = this.localData;
                    this.loadItems();
                    
                });

                setTimeout(() => {
                    console.log('TEST stop long') 
                    this.subscription.unsubscribe();
                }, 2500);
```

I test that if I use TaskSource with CancelAfter all code behind work well but from web (client side) I can't fire the cancellation operation

Comment: This might help https://www.davepaquette.com/archive/2015/07/19/cancelling-long-running-queries-in-asp-net-mvc-and-web-api.aspx

Answer (score 6):

You can add a CancellationToken as parameter of you controller action, you don't need to create a CancellationTokenSource in your controller. This token will be cancelled when the HTTP Request is cancelled by the unsubscribe in angular.

```cs
        [HttpPost]
        public async Task<GetDataOutputDto> GetDataLongOperation(CustomInputDto input, CancellationToken token)
        {
            try
            {
                var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings
                {
                    Error = (sender, args) => {
                        args.ErrorContext.Handled = true;
                    },
                    MissingMemberHandling = MissingMemberHandling.Ignore
                };
        }
        catch(TaskCanceledException e)
        {
            //The observable was unsubscribed in angular
        }
```

Comment: Doesn't seem to enter the catch when cancelled the request, when using `token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested()` it does throw a `OperationCanceledException`.

Comment: Yes cancelling the request doesn't automatically throw the exception. The long running operation needs to throw when the cancellation token is cancelled. If your operation uses framework methods to access a database or filesystem you can use the token as parameter of these methods. If your operation is a computation done in your code you can should add `token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested()` in your code (inside the main loop for exemple) to throw when the request is cancelled

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution all depends in wich way Angular close / cancel connection.

I use this solution [angular-how-to-cancel-http-calls-on-router-change](https://www.freakyjolly.com/angular-how-to-cancel-http-calls-on-router-change/#.X1iGoHn7SUk) angular-how-to-cancel-http-calls-on-router-change

I put it on root.module.ts so now when user change route all connection receive cancellation and it close the flow if is implemented.